# How to write DRF serializer to handle JSON wrappers enveloping data fields defined in my models?

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am writing a REST API using Django Rest Framework and need to know how to write a serializer to handle this json request

```
{
    "user_form": {
        "fields": [
            {"email": "tom.finet@hotmail.co.uk"},
            {"password": "password"},
            {"profile": {
                "username": "Tom Finet",
                "bio": "I like running, a lot.",
                "location": "Switzerland"
            }}
        ]
    }
}
```

Models exist for both User and Profile objects, therefore I am using a ModelSerializer to make serialization easier. However, the relevant user and profile data is wrapped in a `user_form` and `fields` envelop. Therefore, when I make a POST request to create a user the server spits back status code `400` with a `BadRequest`.

Here are the User and Profile serializers

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'profile')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        email_data = validated_data.pop('email')
        password_data = validated_data.pop('password')
        created, user = User.objects.get_or_create_user(
            email=email_data,
            password=password_data
        )
        return user
```

Here is the api create view:

```
def create(self, request):
    user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        user_serializer.save()
    return Response(
        user_serializer.data,
        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
    )
```

What I want to happen is for the serializers to create a user from the json request specified, but I am unaware of how to go about handling the envelops wrapping the user and profile data.

Comment: If possible, I would consider re-designing the request payload rather than creating an ad-hoc solution within your serializer classes. For example, your payload could omit the `user_form`, `fields` and simply post a single dictionary object containing the keys `email`, `password` and `profile`. At this point you'd need a serializer with the fields `email`, `password` and a related serializer for `profile`.

Comment: As @AlexanderCollins said, consider re-designing your json request, otherwise,  deal with it without a serializer, just iterating over the `request.data` dictionary. Handle this json request with a serializer will be more difficult. Each object of request must have a serializer and I believe there is no serializer field capable of handle the `fields` field (a array with different objects inside)

Comment: Exactly @LucasWeyne, The point of django json to model serialization is to take well formed data, validate and parse to model instance. If you must you could use something along the lines of `serializer = UserSerializer({k: v for d in request.data.get('user_form').get('fields') for k, v in d.items()}]` to load the request payload into your serializer (this could be done over multiple lines to keep things clean), then validate the serializer and instantiate an instance of the user model.

Answer (score 1):

Following from my comment,

Consider modifying your post payload (client side) as follows:

```
{
    "email": "tom.finet@hotmail.co.uk",
    "password": "password",
    "profile": {
        "username": "Tom Finet",
        "bio": "I like running, a lot.",
        "location": "Switzerland"
    }
}
```

Following this your current serializer classes should suffice.

If it's not possible to change your post payload on the client, consider extrapolating it using the following comprehension to instantiate your serializer manually within your view:

```
serializer = UserSerializer(data={
    k: v
    for d in request.data.get('user_form').get('fields')
    for k, v in d.items()
})

if not serializer.is_valid():
    # handle invalid serializer error
    pass

# save the new model
serializer.save()
```